# can't remove parameter using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a url like this

```
test.html?dir=asc&end_date=2016-09-23&order=created_at&start_date=2016-08-14
```

i want to remove the parameter using the following javascript

```
function removeParam(uri) {

   uri =  uri.replace(/([&\?]start_date=*$|start_date=*&|[?&]start_date=(?=#))/, '');

   return uri.replace(/([&\?]end_date=*$|end_date=*&|[?&]end_date=(?=#))/, '');
}
```

but it didn't work, anyone know what's wrong with that?

Comment: What is the final output you want to get? `test.html`? Just find the index of `?` and get the substring before it.

Comment: in regex ... =* is 0 or more `=` ... perhaps you meant `=.*`

Comment: Sidenote: Escaping `?` inside character class is unnecessary.

Comment: I used to describe it the same but actually it is more or zero @JaromandaX

Comment: Haha no they are not the same. Lol @JaromandaX

Comment: Well, it's not about how I and you describe it but about how it works in fact. @JaromandaX

Comment: That's why I said *I used to...* since it's a common phrase across articles and docs around Regular Expressions and is easily understandable and imaginal for everyone, mostly beginners, who refers to them in the first place. And since we are talking programmatically, in programming context their order differs a lot. @JaromandaX

Comment: Oh my god, you made me sad by removing your comments. @JaromandaX

Comment: @revo - wasn't constructive

Comment: That's right./#

Answer (score 0):

in modern browsers you can do this quite simply

```
var x = new URL(location.origin + '/test.html?dir=asc&end_date=2016-09-23&order=created_at&start_date=2016-08-14');
x.searchParams.delete('start_date');
x.searchParams.delete('end_date');
var uri = x.pathname.substr(1) + x.search; // substr(1) because you don't have a leading / in your original uri
```

at least, I think it's simpler

Answer (score 0):

Your RegExp is no match!

If you want remove `end_date`, you should:

```
uri.replace(/(end_date=)([^*&]+)/, 'end_date=')
```

And so on.